# Microsoft Power BI Report Builder to render base64 to pdf

Tags: pdf, powerbi, report, reportingservices-2005, rdl

I can render base64 to images with MIME type image/png in SSRS/Power BI Report Builder.
Now I need to render base64 to PDF. Used MIME type 'application/pdf' and I am getting a RED x as result and no PDF/Picture. Anyone know how to render base64 to PDF? Thank you.

I tried different MIME types, and Source settings in Report Builder, no success.